# Unions and intersections amongst classes of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Firstly, it is important to state that I am not a student with a background in foundational mathematics like set theory, yet I am having to learn and understand set theory because I want to teach myself topology (from G.F.Simmons).

The question I present here is a question in one of his introductory chapters

**Q** Let, there be two classes of sets $\left\{A_i\right\}, \left\{B_j\right\}$ such that $\left\{A_i\right\}\subseteq\left\{B_j\right\}$, prove that $\bigcup_iA_i\subseteq\bigcup_jB_j$ and also prove that, $\bigcap_jB_j\subseteq\bigcap_iA_i$.

Although the first part is directly intuitively understandable, I just wanted the experienced people here to comment on the solidity of my mathematical language. Here I present my answer.

**A**

**(1)** If, $$\left\{A_i\right\}\subseteq\left\{B_j\right\}\\
\implies \left\{A_i\right\}\cup\left\{B_j\right\}=\left\{B_j\right\}\\
\implies \left\{B_j\right\}=\left\{X:(X\in \left\{A_i\right\})\lor(X\in \left\{B_j\right\})\right\}\\
\implies \bigcup_jB_j=\left\{x:x\in X:(X\in \left\{A_i\right\})\lor(X\in \left\{B_j\right\})\right\}\\
\bigcup_iA_i=\left\{x:x\in X:X\in \left\{A_i\right\} \right\}\\
\implies\bigcup_iA_i\subseteq\bigcup_jB_j$$

**(2)** If, $$\left\{A_i\right\}\subseteq\left\{B_j\right\}\\
\implies \left\{A_i\right\}\cap\left\{B_j\right\}=\left\{A_i\right\}\\
\implies \left\{A_i\right\} = \left\{X: (X \in \left\{A_i\right\})\land(X\in\left\{B_j\right\})\right\}\\
\implies \bigcap_iA_i=\left\{x:x\in X:(X\in\left\{A_i \right\})\land (X \in \left\{B_j\right\} ) \right\}\\
\bigcap_j B_j=\left\{x:x\in X: X \in\left\{B_j\right\} \right\}\\
\implies \bigcap_j B_j \subseteq \bigcap_i A_i $$

I am not as familiar with the mathematical language of set theory as you guys are, hence I tried to improvise with the limited vocabulary that I had, to make my point. Is this a sufficiently satisfactory proof? If not, I would happily accept any suggestions from your side.

Comment: A pretty good [though incomplete] list of symbols and their meanings is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols).

Comment: @poetasis thanks a lot, what do you think about the solution? Would it make sense to call it a correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a streamlined alternative.
Let K and L be collections of sets with K subset L.

$\cup K \subseteq \cup L.\ $  Proof.
If $x \in \cup K$, then exists A in K with x in A.
Thus exists A in L with x in A.  So $x \in \cup L$

$\cap L \subseteq \cap K.\ $  Proof.
If $x \in \cap L$, then for all A in L, x in A.
Thus for all A in K, x in A.  So $x \in \cap K$

As the two statements are topological duals,
the proof of one implies a proof of the other.